# Service not registering with Consul when running from IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, consul, iis-10

I am running an ASP.NET Core microservice under IIS 10.0, and am trying to register it with Consul on startup. I have added the following code in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ConsulHostedService>();
    services.Configure<ConsulConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("consulConfig"));
    services.AddSingleton<IConsulClient>(p => new ConsulClient(ConfigOverride));
}

private void ConfigOverride(ConsulClientConfiguration config)
{
    var address = Configuration["ConsulConfig:ConsulAddress"];
    config.Address = new Uri(address);
}
```

This works just fine when running as a standalone project, but when running in IIS, the service doesn't register itself until I hit "browse". [According to Cesar de la Torre](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/), ConsulHostedService.Startup should be called during application startup, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Considering the fact this doesn't seem to be an issue when running as a standalone, this seems to be an IIS issue, but I can't figure out which, perhapse just a setting I need to switch. The only one I found that seemed related was "Preload Enabled" in the site's advanced settings, but without success.

In case there is something in my code I'm missing, here's the full Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, ConsulHostedService>();
        services.Configure<ConsulConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("consulConfig"));
        services.AddSingleton<IConsulClient>(p => new ConsulClient(ConfigOverride));
    }

    private void ConfigOverride(ConsulClientConfiguration config)
    {
        var address = Configuration["ConsulConfig:ConsulAddress"];
        config.Address = new Uri(address);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        else
            app.UseHsts();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

And ConsulHostedService:

```
public class ConsulHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private readonly IConsulClient _consulClient;
    private readonly IOptions<ConsulConfig> _consulConfig;
    private readonly ILogger<ConsulHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly IServer _server;
    private string _registrationId;

    public ConsulHostedService(IConsulClient consulClient, IOptions<ConsulConfig> consulConfig,
        ILogger<ConsulHostedService> logger, IServer server)
    {
        _consulClient = consulClient;
        _consulConfig = consulConfig;
        _logger = logger;
        _server = server;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token);
        var uri = GetServerAddress();
        _registrationId = $"{_consulConfig.Value.ServiceId}-{_consulConfig.Value.ServicePort}";
        AgentServiceRegistration registration = MakeConsulRegistration(uri);
        await Register(registration);
    }

    private Uri GetServerAddress()
    {
        var features = _server.Features;
        var addresses = features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
        var address = addresses.Addresses.First();
        return new Uri(address);
    }

    private AgentServiceRegistration MakeConsulRegistration(Uri uri)
    {
        return new AgentServiceRegistration()
        {
            ID = _registrationId,
            Name = _consulConfig.Value.ServiceName,
            Address = $"http://localhost",
            Port = _consulConfig.Value.ServicePort,
            Tags = _consulConfig.Value.ServiceTags,
            Check = MakeConsulCheck(uri)
        };
    }

    private AgentServiceCheck MakeConsulCheck(Uri uri)
    {
        return new AgentServiceCheck()
        {
            HTTP = $"http://localhost:{_consulConfig.Value.ServicePort}/api/meta/status",
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
    }

    private async Task Register(AgentServiceRegistration registration)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Registering in Consul");
        await _consulClient.Agent.ServiceDeregister(registration.ID, _cts.Token);
        await _consulClient.Agent.ServiceRegister(registration, _cts.Token);
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _logger.LogInformation("Deregistering from Consul");
        try
        {
            await _consulClient.Agent.ServiceDeregister(_registrationId, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Deregistration failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "This works just fine when running as a standalone project, but when running in IIS, the service doesn't register itself until I hit "browse"." That's exactly what is expected. IIS/ASP.NET Core module only initializes your code when the first request comes.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to force a first request? Because natural requests from clients can't logically come before the service is registered with service discovery, and the service needs to be initialized before it can register itself.

Comment: Create a test page in your web app, and then use a script to access it periodically. That's a cross platform approach to warm up the processes, for both IIS and ASP.NET Core, https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1 IIS of course has its own warm up module, but it won't work once you deploy to Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Scripts are blocked (group policy), but it should be possible to figure things out from here ^^

Answer (score 0):

To `warm up` your microservice, you can set `Start Mode` to `AlwaysRunning`. Mode details: [How do I get a .Net Core website hosted in IIS to start immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551660/how-do-i-get-a-net-core-website-hosted-in-iis-to-start-immediately)

But **it sounds like you need to take care of the `first request` yourself as the last step of your deployment process**, because you mentioned that "natural requests" from clients can be used as a `warm up` ones.

Notes: in general `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` are called by the runtime when the app starts according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup). You could also try to work around the problem by configuring your microservice without `Startup` class at all - via `HostBuilder` (similar to `WebHostBuilder`) - check [Using HostBuilder and the Generic Host in .NET Core Microservices](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-generic-host-in-dotnet-core-console-based-microservices). Also have a look at `IHostedService` approach, which might fit to your needs better: [Implementing IHostedService in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice)